# Android GPS returning same location coordinates with different accuracy

Tags: android, gps, rx-java, reactive-programming, android-location

My app uses `ReactiveLocationProvider` to get location update using `LocationRequest` object. Here's the full code:

```
mLocationRequestPassive = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequestPassive.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);     
mLocationRequestPassive.setFastestInterval(60000);     
mLocationRequestPassive.setInterval(PASSIVE_UPDATE_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS * 1000);
mSubscriptions.add(mReactiveLocationProviderPassive
                           .getUpdatedLocation(mLocationRequestPassive)
                           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                           .subscribe(this::onLocationChanged,
                                      throwable -> Timber.w(throwable,
                                                   "Location request error")));
```

It works almost 95% of times, but sometimes it starts to send repeated lat/lng. The accuracy is different, though. Has it ever happened to anyone else? Is there any fix for this.

I'm using following versions of the libraries

- `compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.9@aar'`
- `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'`

**UPDATE**

The vehicle was moving during this time. So, adding `setSmallestDisplacement` just changes it from location updates with same lat/lng to no location updates.

Comment: You could have a look at [LocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say this. The vehicle moved in that duration while this happened.

Comment: Please define what behavior you are expecting to see.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why does it happen in the service, but generally, you could use `distinctUntilChanged(BiPredicate)` to filter out small changes in subsequent items:

```java
Observable.just(10.0, 10.1, 10.15, 10.162, 11.0)
.distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) -> Math.abs(prev - curr) < 0.09)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```